# What about the no-repeat property on background images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### Preconditions

- I have a series of equal sized small images that I have tiled next to each other.
- I have a div the size of one of the images.
- I use setInterval to loop through the images to produce an animation by offsetting the background by the image width.

### Example

```
<html>                                                                         
<head>                                                                         
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>                                                                    
        #animation{                                                                
            width: 100px;                                                      
            height: 100px;                                                     
            overflow: hidden;                                                  
            background: url('tile.jpg') no-repeat 0px 0px;                 
            border: 10px solid red;                                            
        }                                                                      
    </style>
    <script>
        var nr_of_images = 10;
        var image_width = 100;
        var first_position = '0px';
        var last_position = ((1-nr_of_images)*image_width)+'px';               

        function animate_one_frame(){
            if(jQuery('#animation').css('background-position').split(' ')[0] == last_position){
                jQuery('#animation').css('background-position', first_position + ' 0px');
            }else{
                jQuery('#animation').css('background-position', '-=' + image_width + ' 0px');
            }
        }
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval('animat_one_frame()', 200);
        });
    </script>
</head>                                                                        
<body>                                                                         
  <div id="animation">
  </div>                                                                       
</body>                                                                        
</html>
```

So in the example above the background will be *shifted* one image at a time every 200ms. When the last image in the tile is reached the offset will be reset to the first image.

### Question

The same visual result as in the example above could be accomplished by removing the **no-repeat** property from the background definition and by shifting in eternity in the same direction without resetting to the offset at *the last* image.

1. **What is the pros and cons with this approach?**
2. **Is any of the approaches preferred?**

Comment: I'd say that using a repeated background makes it much simpler as you could do the whole thing in one line of code - a `setInterval()` with an `animate()` inside it.  No need for extra functions or calculations.  Other than that, they really are exactly the same.

Comment: Yep I agree in the functional sense. But are there no rendering or overflow issues to consider in browsers?

Comment: Rendering wise the browser will keep up - its not actually offsetting a repeated image, its probably reducing the offset you provide. Its the javascript offset size i'd worry about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. What are the pros and cons with this approach?**

There are no inherent advantages or disadvantages to this approach, apart from one thing: the size of the offset. If you leave this going on indefinitely, you would slowly start slowing down because the offset drawing starts to become incredibly large. Your number keeps increasing, and the longer you wait you inevitably bump it to an out of range javascript number, or the so-called 'Javascript infinity', or out of range floating point.

**2. Is any of the approaches preferred?**

It is preferred to reset, if not for the above reason, then just because it allows your own sanity in debugging, allowing you to see the number reset in your live and active code and knowing that the numbers are correct.